# Formas o técnicas para disminuir la redundancia en base de datos

Tags: mysql

Tengo un problema de diseño en la base de datos, he leido que las bases de datos cada que se crea un circulo en relaciones de tablas es porque hay redundancia de datos y no es parte de las buenas practicas, le doy vueltas pero no consigo quitar el circulo sin la necesidad de crear mas tablas.

la base es para la administración de proyectos donde la empresa tiene proyectos, un proyecto tiene requerimientos, los requerimientos tienen asesores y desarrolladores.

El problema que tengo es con la tabla requerimientos, un requerimiento puede tener (n) asesores y (n) desarrolladores, los desarrolladores y los asesores los obtengo de la tabla usuarios que tiene el campo rol para identificar quienes son desarrolladores, asesores o lideres de proyecto, para no tener un circulo en las relaciones solo lo he logrado creando las tablas desarroladores, asesores, lideres de proyecto, pero las tablas tienen la misma informacion, nombre, usuario, contraseña

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

```
 create table usuario (
        id_usuario int NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT PRIMARY KEY,
        correo varchar(80) COLLATE utf8_spanish_ci,
        contrasena varchar(80) COLLATE utf8_spanish_ci,
        nombre varchar(80) COLLATE utf8_spanish_ci,
        apellidos varchar(80) COLLATE utf8_spanish_ci,
        fecha_registro DATETIME,
        origen_registro int,
        genero int,
        rol int
      )ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8 COLLATE=utf8_spanish_ci;

 create table empresa(
    id_empresa int NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT PRIMARY KEY,
    razon_social varchar(254) COLLATE utf8_spanish_ci
  )ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8 COLLATE=utf8_spanish_ci;

create table proyecto_empresa(
    id_proyecto_empresa int NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT PRIMARY KEY,
    id_empresa int,
    nombre varchar(254) COLLATE utf8_spanish_ci,
    plataforma int,
    descripcion varchar(254) COLLATE utf8_spanish_ci,
    tecnologia varchar(254) COLLATE utf8_spanish_ci,
    ubicacion int,
    url varchar(254) COLLATE utf8_spanish_ci,
    detalles varchar(254) COLLATE utf8_spanish_ci,
    FOREIGN KEY (id_empresa) REFERENCES empresa(id_empresa)
  )ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8 COLLATE=utf8_spanish_ci;

create table requerimiento_proyecto(
    id_requerimiento_proyecto int NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT PRIMARY KEY,
    id_proyecto_empresa int,
    nombre varchar(254) COLLATE utf8_spanish_ci,
    descripcion varchar(254) COLLATE utf8_spanish_ci,
    estado int,
    fecha_solicitud DATE,
    fecha_entrega DATE,
    gantter varchar(254) COLLATE utf8_spanish_ci,
    prioridad int,
    FOREIGN KEY (id_proyecto_empresa) REFERENCES proyecto_empresa(id_proyecto_empresa)
  )ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8 COLLATE=utf8_spanish_ci;

create table contacto(
    id_contacto int NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT PRIMARY KEY,
    nombre varchar(80) COLLATE utf8_spanish_ci,
    telefono varchar(80) COLLATE utf8_spanish_ci,
    correo varchar(80) COLLATE utf8_spanish_ci,
    rol int
  )ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8 COLLATE=utf8_spanish_ci;

create table solicita_requerimiento(
    id_solicita_requerimiento int NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT PRIMARY KEY,
    id_contacto int,
    id_requerimiento_proyecto int,
    FOREIGN KEY (id_requerimiento_proyecto) REFERENCES requerimiento_proyecto(id_requerimiento_proyecto),
    FOREIGN KEY (id_contacto) REFERENCES contacto(id_contacto)
  )ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8 COLLATE=utf8_spanish_ci;

 create table tarea_requerimiento(
    id_tarea_requerimiento int NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT PRIMARY KEY,
    id_requerimiento_proyecto int,
    nombre_tarea varchar(254) COLLATE utf8_spanish_ci,
    descripcion_tarea varchar(254) COLLATE utf8_spanish_ci,
    estado_tarea int,
    FOREIGN KEY (id_requerimiento_proyecto) REFERENCES requerimiento_proyecto(id_requerimiento_proyecto)
  )ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8 COLLATE=utf8_spanish_ci;

create table asesor_requerimiento(
    id_asesor_requerimiento int NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT PRIMARY KEY,
    id_requerimiento_proyecto int,
    id_usuario int,
    FOREIGN KEY (id_requerimiento_proyecto) REFERENCES requerimiento_proyecto(id_requerimiento_proyecto),
    FOREIGN KEY (id_usuario) REFERENCES usuario(id_usuario)
  )ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8 COLLATE=utf8_spanish_ci;

create table desarrolador_requerimiento(
    id_desarrolador_requerimiento int NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT PRIMARY KEY,
    id_requerimiento_proyecto int,
    id_usuario int,
    FOREIGN KEY (id_requerimiento_proyecto) REFERENCES requerimiento_proyecto(id_requerimiento_proyecto),
    FOREIGN KEY (id_usuario) REFERENCES usuario(id_usuario)
  )ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8 COLLATE=utf8_spanish_ci;

create table revision(
    id_revision int NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT PRIMARY KEY,
    id_requerimiento_proyecto int,
    fecha DATETIME,
    FOREIGN KEY (id_requerimiento_proyecto) REFERENCES requerimiento_proyecto(id_requerimiento_proyecto)
  )ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8 COLLATE=utf8_spanish_ci;
```

Comment: no es mas facil que agregues solo una tabla que se llame, por ejemplo, roles, y asi ya solamente indicas que tipo de usuario es?

Comment: si esta, si te fijas el campo rol es int, esta de esa manera porque tengo una tabla catalogo roles, no creí necesario ponerla al tener int en el campo rol

Comment: Como dice Macx, debes eliminar las tablas desarrollador y asesor_requerimiento las dos las sustituyes con requerimiento_asignacion y alli se agrega UsuarioID y tipo usuario (asesor, desarrollador, scrum master, tester).

Comment: Aparte de lo que te dice miguel, no se donde leiste que las relaciones circulares son malas. No hay reglas estrictas para las bases de datos. pueden ser malas como buenas. Aca no hay redundancia de datos.. mas bien hay una sobre clarificacion de los mismos (con este modelo, ciertas consultas son mucho mas simples). Redundancia es guardar el mismo dato una y otra vez.. aca, no guardas el mismo una y otra vez

Comment: lo de la redundancia de datos y relaciones circulares, pues viene de universidad, los profesores siempre indican que no se debe hacer las relaciones circulares. pero Miguel dio en el clavo